# Is it possible to IGNORE a specific route/DTO from appearing in ServiceStack Metadata output

Tags: servicestack

I have a service defined with a number routes.  All working good.

Their is one function/DTO I do not want to show up when viewing the auto METADATA.

Is there an Attribute to mark this DTO not to show up in the MetaData output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Restrict` attribute on your services to restrict the visibility of the service. For example to restrict the service to only being visible while viewing the metadata locally you can use:

```cs
[Restrict(VisibleLocalhostOnly = true)]
```

If you also want to prevent access in addition to visibility you can use:

```cs
[Restrict(LocalhostOnly = true)]
```

See the documentation on Restricting Services for additional restrictions. You may also find the source code of the [`Restrict` attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/RestrictAttribute.cs) useful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Scott -

Thanks, while that "greys" out the XML/JSON/JSV/CSV/SOAP links, it still lists the SERVICE under the Operations.

I have a Fallback Service, with one Operation.  I'd really like for that and one other operation to not even appear in the list of Operations at all.